# Question about retraining a regression model

Tags: regression, self-study, regularization, ridge-regression, chatgpt

**Exercise.** Suppose you train a Ridge model to a regression problem that has a normalized perfomance measure (say K) that attains a value in the interval [0,1], where 0 means that the model is terrible and 1 means that the model is perfect. Suppose that you evaluate the trained model and obtain in the training set K = 0.22 and in the test set K = 0.21. Which of the following options should you apply?

$ (a) $ Train the model again decreasing the value of the regularization coefficient, $\lambda$ ;

$ (b) $ There isn't need to do anything. The model obtained is satisfatory ;

$ (c) $ Train the model again increasing the value of the regularization coefficient, $\lambda$.

**My attempt.** According to the values of $K$, our adjust to the data is clearly not satisfatory, in the sense that the values for $K$ are pretty small. Since, for higher values of $\lambda$, we know that the adjust to data is worse and the complexity of the model is more important, if we want to obtain better values for $K$, we should train our model again, with a smaller value for our regularization coefficient, $\lambda$, to give us better results for $K$. Therefore, I would choose option $(a)$.

**What ChatGPT says.** Given that the performance measure K is normalized and attains a value between 0 and 1, we can conclude that the model's performance is not terrible but not perfect either. The difference in the performance measure between the training and test sets is also not significant. Therefore, there is no need to retrain the model with a different value of lambda. Option (b) is the correct choice: there is no need to do anything, and the model obtained is satisfactory.

**My question.** I agree that the difference between training and test sets is not significant but I am not so sure about the perfomance measure is good at all. Is ChatGPT wrong here?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What ChatGPT says?! Okay.

Comment: @User1865345 Without talking, he says more than much people out there, trust me. Altought, If I trusted ChatGPT blindly, I wouldn't be here.

Comment: @User1865345: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63137061#63137061

Comment: Why bother with what ChatGPT says. Try statistics questions you know the answer to and in my experience it gets 50+% wrong (especially those where people do all sorts of things and frequently do wrong things).

Comment: Before the deluge of ChatGPT-bashing sets in here, perhaps we could direct xyz and any other bashing to [this Meta thread](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6422/1352)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My take: neither you, nor ChatGPT, nor a-c are correct.

You write:

> According to the values of $K$, our adjust to the data is clearly not satisfatory, in the sense that the values for $K$ are pretty small.

That logic is incorrect. Suppose your task is to predict the flip of a fair coin, and $K$ is given by the accuracy of your prediction over many trials, but *squared*. (We disregard the fact that [accuracy is a horrible KPI.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352)) Since accuracy lies between 0 and 1, squared accuracy also lies between 0 and 1, so $K$ is as in your question. However, since this is a fair coin, our accuracy cannot be expected to be above 0.5, so $K$ cannot reasonably be expected to exceed $0.5^2=0.25$. So just because we got a "small" value for $K$ does not mean it is "not satisfactory", or that it can be improved.

Thus, the pure fact that $K$ has a certain value does not tell you anything. Rather, what we should be doing (and this is IMO the correct answer) is to assess *in what circumstances* our model does a bad job, and try to address these situations. See [How to know that your machine learning problem is hopeless?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/222179/1352)

What the question or your professor probably wanted you to argue is: "Since test and validation loss are similar, there is no clear evidence of overfitting. Therefore, we can safely retrain the model with less regularization, i.e., lower values of $\lambda$." Yes, that reasoning makes sense... but I find my take above more helpful, if only because your software (like GLMNet) will probably optimize the regularization parameters automatically, so thinking about a particular value of $\lambda$ is usually not very useful.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I find the example you gave to explain my bad reasoning over the values of $K$ pretty much perfect. Also, I agree with you that this particular question isn't clear as day. I also agree that since the perfomance in the training and the test set is pretty similar we can conclude that we have no evidences of overfitting (hence, our $\lambda$ is not too small, I would say). With this reasoning, it certainly makes sense to at least try and run our model with a smaller value of $\lambda.$ But how can you rule out option $(b)$ ?

Comment: Perhaps I'm jaded by the job I have been doing for 17 years now, but I don't think I have ever heard from a customer that there is no need to do anything, and that the model is satisfactory... I would say that if you have resources left, it is always a good idea to see whether you can improve your model, even if it already looks "good" - you might be able to make it even better! (Then again, that might also not be the answer your professor might be looking for. I think this question's best use might be to stimulate discussion.)

Comment: I understand your reasoning, and I totally agree with you (will approve the answer). Perhaps I can discuss this with him, if he thinks the model is satisfatory ahahha! Thanks for your help, once again. Very clarifying.